# Why $L^{r}(X)\cap L^{t}(X)\subset L^{s}(X)$ for $1<r<s<t$?

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis, banach-spaces

I am working on this homework problem, and I am totally stuck:

Let $(X,\mu)$ be a measure space, and let $1 \leq r < s < t < \infty$.  Prove that there exist constants $\alpha,\beta>0$ so that
$$
\|f\|_s \;\leq\; \|f\|_r^\alpha\,\|f\|_t^\beta
$$
for any measurable function $f\colon X\to\mathbb{R}$.  Use this to show that
$$
L^r(X) \cap L^t(X) \,\subset\, L^s(X).
$$

I know this is supposed not to be difficult. But I cannot solve it.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**Hint:** Write $\frac{1}{s} = \frac{\alpha}{r} + \frac{\beta}{t}$ and apply [Hölder's inequality](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Holder%27s_inequality).

Comment: I am trying to work out the detail. Thanks

Comment: @user7887: I should have added that you want $\alpha + \beta = 1$, so $0 \lt \alpha, \beta \lt 1$.

Comment: @Theo Buehler: I want to ask how to apply it, the left hand side only has $f$ available, I am thinking I need to make $f$ into $f^{\frac{1}{r}}$ or something, but that looks very ugly.

Comment: @user7887. Very good. Playing around with conjugate exponents can be very tricky sometimes :)

Comment: @user7887: By the way: This is sometimes called *Lyapunov's inequality* or simply *interpolation inequality*.

Comment: @Theo Buehler: Thanks for the information.