# Question on continuous injection between $L^p$ spaces

Tags: real-analysis, lebesgue-integral, lp-spaces

Let ($\Omega, M, \mu$) be a complete measure space. Is it true that $$L^1(\Omega, M, \mu) \cap L^\infty(\Omega, M, \mu) ↪ L^p(\Omega, M, \mu)$$
for all $p \in [1,\infty]$?

May you help me answering this question please? I have no clue

Comment: Perhaps $||f||_p \leq ||f||_1^{1 / p} ||f||_{\infty}^{1 - 1 /p}$.

Comment: Keyword: log-convexity of L^p norms.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In fact something more general is true. If $p < r < q$ then one has the inequality
$$||f||_r \leq ||f||_p^{1/r - 1/q) /(1/p - 1/q)} ||f||_q^{(1/r-1/q)/(1/p-1/q)}.$$
See for instance [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/28589/sharp-interpolation-inequality-for-lebesgue-spaces). This implies that $L^p \cap L^q \subseteq L^r$ always. See also a related discussion [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/163042/p-leqslant-q-leqslant-r-if-f-in-lp-and-f-in-lr-then-f-in-lq?noredirect=1&lq=1).

Comment: Thank you a lot!