# An inequality $\| f \|_{L^p} \leq \| f \|_{L^\infty}^{1 - \frac{2}{p}} \| f \|_{L^2}^{\frac{2}{p}}$

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis, partial-differential-equations

What is the name of this inequality
$$\| f \|_{L^p(\Bbb R^n)} \leq \| f \|_{L^\infty(\Bbb R^n)}^{1 - \frac{2}{p}} \| f \|_{L^2(\Bbb R^n)}^{\frac{2}{p}}$$
for $p > 2$?And how can I prove this?

Comment: (Trivial case of) a basic interpolation inequality, also discussed [here](http://math.stackexchange.com/q/28589) [here](http://math.stackexchange.com/q/31683), and  [here](http://math.stackexchange.com/q/163042)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following generalization is usually called the "log-convexity of $L^p$ norms" (see [Lemma 2](http://terrytao.wordpress.com/2009/03/30/245c-notes-1-interpolation-of-lp-spaces/) and [Lemma 1.11.5](http://books.google.com/books?id=DhWarYBllZAC&lpg=PA162&ots=TFa6g7pYL6&dq=convexity%20of%20lp%20norm&pg=PA162#v=onepage&q=convexity%20of%20lp%20norm&f=false)).

Since $p\frac{q-r}{q-p}+q\frac{r-p}{q-p}=r$ and $\frac{q-r}{q-p}+\frac{r-p}{q-p}=1$, Hölder's Inequality says that
$$
\begin{align}
\int_Mf^r\,\mathrm{d}\mu
&=\int_Mf^{p\large\frac{q-r}{q-p}}f^{q\large\frac{r-p}{q-p}}\,\mathrm{d}\mu\\
&\le\left(\int_Mf^p\,\mathrm{d}\mu\right)^{\Large\frac{q-r}{q-p}}
\left(\int_Mf^q\,\mathrm{d}\mu\right)^{\Large\frac{r-p}{q-p}}\tag{1}
\end{align}
$$
Raising to the $1/r$ power,
$$
\left(\int_Mf^r\,\mathrm{d}\mu\right)^{\Large\frac1r}
\le\left(\int_Mf^p\,\mathrm{d}\mu\right)^{\Large\frac1p\frac pr\frac{q-r}{q-p}}
\left(\int_Mf^q\,\mathrm{d}\mu\right)^{\Large\frac1q\frac qr\frac{r-p}{q-p}}\tag{2}
$$
Thus,
$$
\|f\|_r\le\|f\|_p^{\Large\frac pr\frac{q-r}{q-p}}\|f\|_q^{\Large\frac qr\frac{r-p}{q-p}}\tag{3}
$$
where $\frac pr\frac{q-r}{q-p}+\frac qr\frac{r-p}{q-p}=1$. Setting $\theta=\frac pr\frac{q-r}{q-p}$, $(3)$ can also be written as
$$
\|f\|_r\le\|f\|_p^\theta\,\|f\|_q^{1-\theta}\tag{4}
$$
where
$$
\frac1r=\frac{\theta}{p}+\frac{1-\theta}{q}\tag{5}
$$

---

In the problem at hand, let $p=2$ and $q=\infty$. We get $\theta=2/r$ and
$$
\|f\|_r\le\|f\|_2^{2/r}\,\|f\|_\infty^{1-2/r}\tag{6}
$$

Answer (score 3):

> What is the name of this inequality?

A triviality?

To prove it, note that $|f|^p\leqslant\|f\|_\infty^{p-2}\,|f|^2=c^p\,|f|^2$ pointwise, with $c=\|f\|_\infty^{(p-2)/p}$, and integrate both sides of the inequality, this yields
$$
\|f\|_p^p\leqslant c^p\|f\|_2^2,
$$
which is equivalent to what you want.