# Quick tip: Why is $\vert \vert x \vert \vert_{\infty}^{q-p} \vert \vert x \vert \vert _{p}^{p}\leq \vert \vert x \vert \vert _{q}^{q}$

Tags: sequences-and-series, functional-analysis, lp-spaces, normed-spaces

I a solution I recently saw the following estimation for $1\leq p < q \leq \infty$
and $x \in \ell^{p}$:

$\vert \vert x \vert \vert_{\infty}^{q-p} \vert \vert x \vert \vert _{p}^{p}\leq \vert \vert x \vert \vert _{q}^{q}$

I may be missing something obvious, but how do I get to the above?

Comment: See [this answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/305118), $(4)$ and $(5)$ in particular. However, I think this inequality is backward.

Comment: If the underlying space is one-dimensional, then we have equality