# $L^p$ spaces inclusion

Tags: real-analysis, lp-spaces

Show that for any measurable function $f$ in a measure space, we have:
$$
||f||_p \leq \max\{||f||_r ,||f||_s \}
$$
whenever $0<r<p<s$.
Now by splitting the integrals into parts where $f>1$ and $f\leq 1$, we could easily show that
$$
||f||_p \leq ||f||_r+||f||_s \
$$
But I have no idea how to show the stronger inequality as above.

Comment: Hölder's inequality does the trick: http://math.stackexchange.com/a/28611